# Getting value from JavaScript to Bean

Tags: javascript, java

I would like to Set value to property of managed bean from javascript.
Below are the required files:

The page **sample.xhtml**:

```html
       <h:body>
          <form style="width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;">
              <div class="adjoined-bottom">
                 <div class="grid-container">
             <div class="grid-width-100">
                <div id="editor">
                   <h1>Hello world!</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
          </div>
              </div>
              <div id="content2" style="display: none">
          <p>The number of <code>change</code> events: <strong><span id="changes"></span></strong>.</p>
       </div>
       <h:form>
          <p:commandButton value="Post" 
             action="#{editorController.save}" ajax="false"
             style="width: 50px;height: 30px;font-size: 13px"
                    styleClass="btnClass"/>
       </h:form>
       <h:outputText id="editorcontent2" value="#{editorController.content}" escape="false"/> 
          <script>
             (function () {
                var changesCount = 0;
                       var editor2 = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
                       removePlugins: 'sourcearea'
         } );
                       editor2.on( 'change', function ( ev ) {
                           changesCount++;
                           document.getElementById( 'content2' ).style.display = '';
                           document.getElementById( 'changes' ).innerHTML = changesCount.toString();
                           document.getElementById( 'editorcontent2' ).innerHTML = editor2.getData();
         } );
        })();
                 </script>
                 <script>
                    initSample();
                 </script>
          </form>
   </h:body>
```

The method save on managed bean **EditorController.java**:

```js
public void save()
{   
   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-configuration.xml");
   eDao = ctx.getBean(FacebookerDao.class);
   editor.setEditorContent(content);
   eDao.saveEditor(editor);
}
```

Successfully, the **h:outputText** shows the content of the editor, however after clicking on the button **Post**, the field **editorContent** on DataBase is **NULL**.

Have you please any idea about solving this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```html
<div id="content2" style="display: none">
    <p>The number of <code>change</code> events: <strong><span id="changes"></span></strong>.</p>
   </div>
   <h:outputText id="editorcontent2" value="#{editorController.content}" escape="false"/> 
   <h:form id="formId">
       <h:inputHidden id="x" value="#{editorController.content}" escape="false"/>
       <h:commandButton value="submit" onclick="getEditorData()" action="#{editorController.save}" />
   </h:form>
  
  
   <script>
    (function getEditorData() {
     var changesCount = 0;
     var editor2 = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor', {
      removePlugins: 'sourcearea'
       
  
     } );
     
     editor2.on( 'change', function ( ev ) {
      changesCount++;
      document.getElementById( 'content2' ).style.display = '';
      document.getElementById( 'changes' ).innerHTML = changesCount.toString();
      document.getElementById( 'editorcontent2' ).innerHTML = editor2.getData();
      document.getElementById("formId:x").value = editor2.getData();
     } );
     
    })();
   </script>
```

HTH